# Messenger Platform Reply in Multiple Image Attachment

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-messenger-bot

I want my code to reply to my user a number of times.

I have

```
$photo_dir = "../shop.ewconline.site/products/".$productnum4."/images/*";
```

$productnum4 is a name of the folder inside products that separates them.

example :    `$productnum4 = 5004`;

check how many files inside in this directory, this is about 3 image .jpg files inside

```
$dir = count(glob($photo_dir,GLOB_BRACE));
```

then I would use

```
for($p=1;$p<=$dir;$p++){
```

to loop this link depending on how many is $dir

```
$photo_url[$p] = "https://shop.ewconline.site/products/$productnum/images/$p.jpg";
```

and use this part to respond back to the user

```
$response = [
'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
'message' => [ 
'attachment' => [ 
'type' => 'image',
'payload' => [
'is_reusable' => true,
'url' => $photo_url[$p],
]
],
]
];
}
```

Current Output

**-this would show image-**

user will receive 1 image only.

Expecting an Output of

**-this would show image-**
**-this would show image-**
**-this would show image-**

user will receive 3 image.

Hoping for someone that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing array with key so remove key from array and pass just array. then you will get three url in array.

```
$response = [
'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
'message' => [ 
'attachment' => [ 
'type' => 'image',
'payload' => [
'is_reusable' => true,
'url' => $photo_url, // Removed key
]
],
]
];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Code:

```
$senderId = 1;
$productnum4 = 5004;
$photo_dir = "../shop.ewconline.site/products/".$productnum4."/images/*";

foreach(glob($photo_dir,GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
    $response[]=[
        'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
        'message' => [ 
            'attachment' => [ 
                'type' => 'image',
                'payload' => [
                    'is_reusable' => true,
                    'url' => "https://shop.ewconline.site/products/$productnum/images/$filename";
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
var_export($response);
```

Comment: There is much about your question that I am uncertain about.  Please provide feedback on my suggested code.  I'll improve my answer once you confirm that it works or needs fixing.

Comment: @SteveI Do you want multiple urls in the `payload` subarray?  in the `attachment` subarray? do you want multiple urls in `url`   Please improve your question by expressing your expected result.

Comment: i just want my user to recieve [3 images]. not a url. like (https://shop.ewconline.site/products/5004/images/1.jpg).  i need my user to recieve an actual image. i was able to do it with1 image only using loop but it sends the last image which is [3.jpg]. i need to send the user an actual image which is 1.jpg, 2.jpg. 3.jg

Comment: Okay.  Show me how $response should look

Comment: @SteveI I've posted another suggestion

Comment: SIr? it is different to do it this way. **$answer = "https://shop.ewconline.site/products/$productnum/images/$filename"**  and **'url' => $answer,**

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding sending multiple images @mickmackusa?

Comment: @SteveI You tell me.  You are meant to do your research and only ask a question after you have exhaustively researched.  Ha -- I don't even have a Facebook Account!

Comment: i already read posts and messenger platform documentation before. but nothing seems to show and work. i have tried my own method on loops and arrays. i have tried it all with the best of my knowledge, and then i asked. im just a noob. im still studying. Thank you @,ickmackusa for taking time. much appreciated. will need to surrender in this and move on. haha